ee.dictionary.get("gHM") not returning a mean value in server side
Here is my server side code:
app.post("/process-coordinates", (req, res) => {
  //const coordinates = req.body.coordinates;
  // Here you can perform any Earth Engine operation using the received coordinates
  // Example: Export the region to Earth Engine
  var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("CSP/HM/GlobalHumanModification").first();

  // Convert the floating-point band to integer values.
  var convertedDataset = dataset.select("gHM").multiply(100).toInt();

  // Define the visualization parameters.
  var visualization = {
    bands: ["gHM"],
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    palette: ["0c0c0c", "071aff", "ff0000", "ffbd03", "fbff05", "fffdfd"],
  };

  // Visualize the dataset.
  var visualizedImage = convertedDataset.visualize(visualization);

  // Define an export region covering Metro Manila.
  var exportRegion = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
    [
      [120.87, 14.39],
      [120.85, 14.3],
      [121.05, 14.3],
      [121.03, 14.434],
    ],
  ]);

  // Compute the mean pixel value within the Metro Manila region.
// Compute the mean pixel value within the Metro Manila region.
var stats = convertedDataset.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: exportRegion,
  scale: 1000, // Adjust the scale according to your requirements
});

// Check if the key 'gHM' exists in the dictionary
if (stats.contains('gHM')) {
  // Get the mean GHM value from the dictionary.
  var meanGHMValue = stats.get('gHM');
  // Print the computed mean value.
  console.log("Mean GHM value within Metro Manila:", meanGHMValue);
} else {
  console.log("Mean GHM value within Metro Manila not found");
}

  
  // Send a response
  res.status(200).send("Coordinates received successfully");
});

I'm having trouble with generating the mean value from the Google Earth Engine JavaScript library when I'm calling the API from my server. Instead of the mean value,  I am getting:
Mean GHM value within Metro Manila: {
  func: {
    signature_: {
      args: [Array],
      description: 'Extracts a named value from a dictionary.  If the dictionary does not contain the given key, then defaultValue is returned, unless it is null.',
      returns: 'Object',
      name: 'Dictionary.get'
    }
  },
  args: {
    dictionary: {
      func: [Object],
      args: [Object],
      varName: null,
      sourceFrame: null,
      dict_: null
    },
    key: {
      func: null,
      args: null,
      varName: null,
      sourceFrame: null,
      string_: 'gHM'
    }
  },
  varName: null,
  sourceFrame: null
}

in the earth engine code editor I am getting the mean numerical value properly but in my API calls in my server.js its resulting to that long line.

Turns out I need to turn it to a client side data first by using ee.number
here is the snippet:
if (stats.contains('gHM')) {
  // Get the mean GHM value from the dictionary.
  var meanGHMValue = stats.get('gHM');
  var meanValue = ee.Number(meanGHMValue).getInfo();

it resulted to a number after this. I got confused because I did not have to do this in the ee code editor.
